# How to throttle inbound bandwidth in Windows using Windivert?

Tags: c++, windows, network-programming

I am trying to throttle the inbound bandwidth of my Windows machine using Windivert. I have tried clumsy previously but I don't want to use the UI, rather I want to throttle the bandwidth with the help of a script. Does anyone know how to do it?